# How to contine function after changing page

Tags: javascript

This is my first question so please be kind.  I have the following function:-

```
function MoveCarouselPage(page)
{

   var sPath=window.location.pathname;
   var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
   document.cookie="savepage=" + page;

   if (sPage == "index.php")
   {
   Carousel1Page(page);
   }
   else
   {
   window.location = '/index.php';
   var lastpage = getCookie('savepage');
   alert(lastpage);
   //Commands here don't work.
   }
}
```

The functions finds the current page name and if it's index.php it runs the function Carousel1Page.  Which works just fine.

However if the current page is not index.php it opens index.php and executes more code.  The alert quickly flashes up and disappears and contains the correct value of lastpage but I cannot get any code to work past that point.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: What do you think will host your script if there is no page that hosted it originally available?

Comment: What value does `lastpage` have to be in order for you to do what you want?

Comment: A number from 1 to 4.

Comment: BTW - The functions are all contained in an external JS file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "continue" a function on the next page. You would need to make a function in the next page, and execute it on load.

Comment: Does this apply even if the function is on an external JS file too?

Comment: Yes, it does. AFAIK, scripts live in a `window` object corresponding to the page/frame, and their `window` is completely wiped on page load. We're talking armageddon here - nothing survives of the old document, scripts included. When the next page loads, you need to start from scratch, unless your script is executing in another `window` (like if you have frames).

Comment: Thanks will take your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is is you are refreshing the page, after you have figured out that that the page is not `index.php`

I'm not sure what you are trying to here, but I think this is it:

```
 var lastpage = getCookie('savepage');
 if(lastpage == <myvalue>) {
    alert(lastapge);
    window.location = '/index.php';
 }
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is goto index.php and execute a function or maybe a jquery like - $('#Carousel1').carousel("goto,"+lastpage.toString());